# Frequency of a char at every position of inner list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a list of lists.

```
[[A, B, C],[C, B, A],[B, B, B],[C, C, A],[B, C, A]]
```

I want to calculate the frequency "A" at every position of inner list.

Expected output:

```
0.2, 0 , 0.6
```

The inner lists are equal in length.

```
lst = []                                                            
with open("Control_nucleosome.fasta", "r", newline='\n') as report: 
    for line in report:                                             
        lst.append(line)                                            

for x in lst:                                                       
    if x[[0]]
```

I do not know how to approach at the second for loop.

Comment: There are 5 inner list and at first position of every inner list A is present only once. So 1/5 is 0.2. Correct me if I am wrong

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
[inner.count('A')/len(inner) for inner in zip(*lst)]
```

Comment: Hi @nauer. is there any way to find the frequency of A or B using regrex or any such method.
The expected output would be now 0.6, 0.6 , 0.8

Comment: Simply sum the frequencies. `[(inner.count('A') + inner.count('B'))/len(inner) for inner in zip(*lst)]`

Answer (score 2):

You need:

```
x = [['A', 'B', 'C'],['C', 'B', 'A'],['B', 'B', 'B'],['C', 'C', 'A'],['B', 'C', 'A']]

per = []

for i in range(len(x[0])):
    per.append(len([j[i] for j in x if j[i]=='A'])/len(x))

print(per)
```

Output:

```
[0.2, 0.0, 0.6]
```

Comment: The inner list length is not 3, it may extend to 200 but always same in length.

Comment: Hi @AkshayNevrekar. is there any way to find the frequency of A or B using regrex or any such method. The expected output would be now 0.6, 0.6 , 0.8

Answer (score 1):

You can loop through the original list and then loop through the inner loops to find the answer like:

```
x = [['A', 'B', 'C'],['C', 'B', 'A'],['B', 'B', 'B'],['C', 'C', 'A'],['B', 'C', 'A']]
answer = [0,0,0]
for ele in x:
    for idx,j in enumerate(ele):
        if j == 'A':
            answer[idx]+=1
for idx,i in enumerate(answer):
    answer[idx] = i / len(x)
```

Output is :

```
[0.2, 0.0, 0.6]
```

Comment: Thanks Harshit, but these nested loop will take lots of time when u have larger list. Anyway Its working...

Answer (score 0):

This may help:

```
import pandas as pd
li = [['A', 'B', 'C'],
      ['C', 'B', 'A'],
      ['B', 'B', 'B'],
      ['C', 'C', 'A'],
      ['B', 'C', 'A']]

Li = pd.DataFrame(li)
L = Li.where(Li=='A',0).where(Li!='A',1)
print(L.mean())
```